# How to restrict Internet, not just web, access for the guest account?

Tags: network, permission

How do we set up the **guest account** so it **restricts Internet access to all applications and scripts in all ports**?

Using parental controls only restricts web access, and I'm looking how to prevent any application to access the Internet.

I'm looking for a **free** solution that works even if the (guest) user runs malicious scripts. USB access is required for the guest account.

In Ubuntu we can restrict user access with a command like this:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner example_user -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please read this carefully and have another device with internet access, in case you are locking yourself out.**

In OS X you will use the OpenBSD based tool `pf` which stands for "packet filter".

- Helpful man pages are `man pfctl` and `man pf.conf`
- You need sudo access.

Edit `/etc/pf.conf` to your desired needings:
An example pf.conf would be simple as this and look like this

```
## blocking rule
block out user guest
```

Now activate pfctl with `sudo pfctl -e` and load your config with
`sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf`.

For checking the syntax of the config file you can use `pfctl -nf /etc/pf.conf`.
If you want to deactivate the firewall, pass the command `pfctl -d`.

Testing the new configuration is as simple as `curl -I apple.stackexchange.com`. The firewall should block this for you.

However, I'd be careful with restrictions. If you are losing your Mac or it gets stolen, the guest account is the only account which one will be has access too(hopefully) which in return should have access to the internet to track it down(if "Find My Mac" is enabled).